# StringComparison.InvariantCulture Clarification?

Tags: c#, string, unicode, invariantculture

According To MSDN : `StringComparison.InvariantCulture` :

> Specifies the culture, case, and **sort** rules to be used by certain overloads of the String.Compare and 
>    String.Equals methods.

Well , I'm not doing *any* sort here in my sample  , And still don't understand why does it yield the result it yield :

```
/*1*/   void Main()
/*2*/   {
/*3*/        string s1 = "lasst";
/*4*/        string s2 = "laßt"; 
/*5*/        Console.WriteLine (s1.Equals(s2, StringComparison.InvariantCulture));  
/*6*/        //True
/*7*/        
/*8*/        
/*9*/        
/*10*/       string s3 = "hello";
/*11*/       string s4 = "héllo"; 
/*12*/       Console.WriteLine (s3.Equals(s4, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)); 
/*13*/       //False
/*14*/   }
```

`InvariantCulture` uses comparison rules based on **english**, but without any regional variations

1) So why  it says that `lasst` is equal to `laßt` ? (one doesnt even has an english char...)

2) And why ( if it's flatten to english)`hello` is not equal to `héllo` ?

Comment: It's not "flattened to English" - it's just that the rules are *based* on English. I think for more details you should probably look at unicode.org, which is likely to go into this in a *lot* of detail.

Comment: @JonSkeet Jon, But `ß` is no an english char so how can it be based on english?

Comment: "Based on" != "exactly the same as".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relevant snippet from the book CLR via C#

> **Note** When the Compare method is not performing an ordinal comparison,
>   it performs character expansions. A character expansion is when a
>   character is expanded to multiple characters regardless of culture. In
>   the above case, the German Eszet character ‘ß’ is always expanded to
>   ‘ss.’ Similarly, the ‘Æ’ ligature character is always expanded to
>   ‘AE.’ So in the code example, the second call to Compare will always
>   return 0 regardless of which culture I actually pass in to it.

You string "héllo" does not get transformed by character expansion internally, and so is not considered equal to "hello".

Comment: thanks Let  me see if i got it : the `ß` char sounds like `ss` so there is an internal rule which expand is to `ss` and that's why its equal.  and `é` does NOT has a rule which expand it ( it is not expandable---- p.s. why ?  becuase it doesnt sounds the same ?) and thats why it is different ?

Comment: _sounds like `ss` so there is an internal rule_ - of course not, this rule is deeply entrenched in German custom.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I dont understnad - What part exactly in .net indicates that "‘ß’ is always expanded to ‘ss`." ?

Comment: I think Chris just quoted it here. Pity there is no link (yet).

Comment: @Royi Namir, you'll have to ask a German speaker about the equivalence of "ß" and "ss", as I only have the text quoted above to base my answer off unfortunately. I tried drilling down through the CompareTo method to see if I could find where this character expansion is happening, but couldn't see it before I ran into a native call to InternalCompareString.